# Filter is not executed in C# WebAPI even though it is registered globally

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, filter

I am doing a WebAPI with a filter which is intended to authenticate users, but whenever I call GET, PUT, POST or DELETE, my filter method isn´t triggered.

I have already read many answers saying the following stuff:

- Use an IAuthorizationFilter
- Use an IAuthenticationFilter
- Use an ActionFilterAttribute

And also:

- Apply the attribute at the top of controller or action
- Register the filter in FilterConfig and register global filters in Global.Asax

Tried all of them:

**Filter:**

```
    namespace CumminsGroup.Filters
{
    public class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("filterContext");
            //use filterContext.HttpContext.Request...
        }
    }
}
```

**ApiController:**

```
    namespace CumminsGroup.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [AuthenticationFilter]
    public class UserGroupsController : ApiController
    {        
        // GET: api/Groups
        public IQueryable<Group> GetGroups()
        {
            return db.Groups.Include("GroupUsers").Where(u=>u.status=="active");
        }
```

**FilterConfig:**

```
namespace CumminsGroup
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
            //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax:**

```
namespace CumminsGroup
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);           
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Still when a do an HTTP request, the filter is skiped.
The only moment when the filter funcion is called is right before the home page controller, when I run the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem. nothing helped. I abandoned asp.net after scouring the net for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you discern between MVC and WebAPI filters?

"GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters" vs "GlobalFilters.Filters"

```
MVCConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
WebApiConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
```

Comment: I Solved this problem already... I was importing filters from MVC instead of WebAPI! Thank you!

Comment: I am confused! Here http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-filters it refers to `IActionFilter` as being part of WebAPI. But trying to do a `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter())` fails. How do you write an action filter for webAPI? The `IFilter` interface, used in WebAPI, has no members to implement! :O

Comment: You may be trying to register a MVC filter to the WebApi configuration or vice-versa.   The IFilter is just a common interface to add different filter types to a single configuration collection.  Extending the abstract classes would be allot easier.